# OpenVPN - No server certificate verification method has been enabled

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, vps

I work this tutorial over https://zaufanatrzeciastrona.pl/post/bezpieczna-komorka-na-wakacje-czyli-jak-sie-nie-dac-podsluchac-w-cudzej-sieci-wifi/#comment-56612 I did everything as in this tutorial, but I have a trouble. When I want to connect with my VPN network I get this massage.

**No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.**

I don't know what I should do. Somebody know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Pls add `ns-cert-type server`in your client conf file and try again.

Comment: ok, I did as you had said, but appear new problem. Your "ns-cert-type server" I had to wrote as "--remote-cert-tls" and now I hava this problem "openvpn exited with error exit code = 1". What do I do now?

Comment: I guess your syntax is wrong (the "--" in front). You should go to the page given in the error log above  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm and try the options (according to the openvpn version you are using)given there in client config file.